# Convert multi-dimensional table to a list in excel

Tags: excel

I'm trying to convert a multi-dimensional table of water quality data to a list in Excel 2010. I have 4,000 records that include 90 sites, 705 dates, and 96 water quality parameters. I need to convert the table to a list where each record includes site, date, parameter name, and value. I'm familiar with how to convert a 2-D cross-tab table to a list but this doesn't fit my situation. Hoping to find a formula-based solution using INDEX MATCH or other functions. Here is a sample data set. Thank you [Screen shot - data subset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mI2B.png)

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. The question you have posted does not fall in the scope of questions discussed here. Please refer to the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to see what kind of questions you can ask here. You have to provide something you've tried and errors or the unexpected you're getting. Regards.

Comment: Can you show us what you would like the list to look like? I might be able to help a bit if I can see what the expected output should be.